# TS2570: Property 'getResources' does not exist on type 'Promise<ResourcesLoader>'

Tags: typescript, async-await

I am trying to use `await import` to load some dependency in the main module in runtime.

Main module:

```
async function getResourceLoader() {
  const { ResourcesLoader } = await import('support/seldomUseResource');
  return new ResourcesLoader();
}


function doWork() {
  const loader = getResourceLoader();
  const { file1, file2 } = loader.getResources(); // Error here
```

The resource loader module:

```
export class ResourcesLoader {

  constructor() {

  }

  public getResources() {
    return {
      resource1,
      resource2,
    };
  }
}
```

At this line

```
const { file1, file2 } = loader.getResources();
```

, I am getting this error:

```
TS2570: Property 'getResources' does not exist on type 
'Promise<ResourcesLoader>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?
```

What did I miss?  How can I convert the Promise into the results I expect (namely `{ file1, file2 }` above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should apply `async` to the caller function i.e.

```
async function doWork() {
  const loader = await getResourceLoader();
  const { file1, file2 } = loader.getResources();
```